# Consolidate tags "vehicles" and "transportation"?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

"Vehicles" is a tag without definition. When I tried to fill it in, I found that the description I wanted to use was basically already used by "transportation". So I looked at the questions.

The thorium-powered steam car is under "transportation". 
[Could a photonic engine actually work?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56975/could-a-photonic-engine-actually-work) is under "vehicles". 
etc...

Looking back and forth between the two, the questions that these tags have been used for are pretty much interchangeable.

I recognize that there is some broadness to transportation -- there's one about sand worms, for example, that would possibly not be under "vehicles". But I still propose consolidating these into synonyms for each other, and making "transportation" the primary tag.

Comment: With the exception of teleportation (which has its own tag), transportation and vehicle are basically the same thing (and yes, sand worms are vehicles). They probably should be merged into transportation.

Comment: I agree with @PatJ completely. Nearly all questions with the tags will overlap, and those that do not have their own tags.

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree. No one would consider a horse to be a kind of vehicle, and no one can give me a name of vehicle someone is using when he teleports with magic.

Of course, when it comes to vehicle design, stress might be on other things than when it comes to deciding which mode of transportation is most feasible, or what technologies of building roads would be available.

These tags overlap a bit, but are not synonyms.

Comment: Yes, this sounds a bit like [the case of *spaceflight* versus *spaceships*](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3937/29).

Answer (score 3):

`Transportation` covers methods, such questions as:

- [How would society be affected by ultra-highspeed travel?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34887/how-would-society-be-affected-by-ultra-highspeed-travel)
- [Maximum price gaps of commodity between two cities](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32078/maximum-price-gaps-of-commodity-between-two-cities)
- [Why would canals exist long before railways?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17626/why-would-canals-exist-long-before-railways)

Where as `Vehicles` tends to focus on the actual objects doing the transporting:

- [Solar Powered Vehicles](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/60905/solar-powered-vehicles)
- [Microfilaments on wheels would save fuel?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/53957/microfilaments-on-wheels-would-save-fuel)
- [Clockwork vehicles](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32321/clockwork-vehicles)

Obviously there is a lot of cross over - mostly with `Transportation` being used to ask questions about specific builds of vehicle rather than a general transportation question.

I would say keep the tags separate - if you are searching specifically for ideas about vehicles it sorts some of these out for you. However there is a difference between how the tags would be used ideally and how they are used in practice.

Comment: So you would support more of a sweep through the questions and cleaning up the tag usages?

Comment: @SRM Whilst that is a possibility it is only a temporary solution. The root problem is in the fact that people don't see the distinction so clearly.

Comment: That's my position (that people don't differentiate) and why I support amalgamating them into a single tag.