# Sandbox for Proposed Tag Edits

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki, sandbox

### The point of this post is to discuss potential

- Tag wiki and excerpt edits
- Tag creation and deletion
- Tag blacklisting
- Tag synonymization and merging

... because a meta post for every proposed change fills up the question list relatively *quickly*.

**Answers should include:**

- **One** suggestion each (multiple answers per person are welcome)
- Links to the tag's wiki, definitions, and **all** other information relevant to your argument
- **Reasoning** for all suggested changes
- That the tag is for **meta** (if it is) to avoid confusion

The comments can be used for discussion, and after a consensus is reached, the change should be implemented by the requester.

- If they do not have the ability to implement that change, the post can be **flagged for moderator attention** with a [polite request](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/4437/28639) for implementation. The post can be deleted after the change is confirmed.
- If the suggestion is controversial, it is not recommended to flag or push the idea until an agreement is reached.

Remember that **meta tags** are also in need of cleanup! Don’t forget to check the [meta review](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review) from time to time.

**Happy tagging!**

Comment: Good idea -- this should be easier to manage than individual questions.

Comment: Do you feel we currently have a problem on the site with conflicting tag wiki edits? I sort of fail to see what problem this post aims to solve. The normal review system should be able to handle this, and the only reason I can see why it wouldn't is if there are lots of conflicting editing back and forth.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Read down the meta questions list for the past ~week. There are quite a few posts about tag wiki edits! This post aims to clear out the list in the future, as well as provide a place for discussion and reasoning, which the suggested edit menu does not allow.

Comment: Sorry but I had the idea first, almost 2 years ago! : http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/putting-tags-in-order-on-the-main-site

Comment: I agree that it's important to have a functional tag system to be able to find questions on a specific topic. But it's very hard to use tags consistently.

Comment: @Vincent Ah, sorry! It seems that post is now inactive but if you feel this is a duplicate and the old one can be revived I will help close this one. Alternatively feel free to transfer unsettled discussions from that post to this that you want to revive them.

Comment: No, it's probably outdated anyway.

Comment: @Vincent Alright, feel free to join the discussion here and add new suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

## Synonymize [society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society) and [anthropology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anthropology)

Anthropology means "the study of human society" and therefore applies to most society questions. If there are outliers, they can be tagged as necessary, but it seems reasonable to remap anthropology to society.

See
[Do we want the anthropology tag?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4427/do-we-want-the-anthropology-tag) for previous discussion.

Answer (score 4):

## Blacklist [life](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life)

The tag has had a [long, long journey](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4439/the-end-of-life-as-we-know-it?noredirect=1#comment12017_4439), and at every step of the way, we've decided we don't want it. Deletion hasn't worked, nor has writing an inclusive wiki.

It seems a blacklist is the only way to permanently get rid of it.

Comment: While I'm not against blacklisting it - what ought we do, then, with questions where the tag fits and are difficult to replace? As example [this question about life developing in a flat world](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/69339/how-can-a-flat-sheet-of-cells-develop-complexity-and-even-intelligence), what other tags can replace it - it is an interesting question and simply removing the tag "life" would make it harder to find the question unless a new, appropriate one, can be used.

Comment: @Mrkvička [tag:biology], [tag:origin-of-life], [tag:evolution]

Comment: I would personally think that biology is borderline for it, but the other two might fit fairly well. Fair point, I vote for a blacklist.

Answer (score 2):

## Synonymize [vehicles](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicles) and [transportation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation)

See [Consolidate tags "vehicles" and "transportation"?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4353/consolidate-tags-vehicles-and-transportation) for prior discussion. Nearly all transportation occurs in vehicles, and if it doesn't, it usually has its own tag, like [teleportation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teleportation).

I'm suggesting we remap vehicles to transportation / make transportation the main tag.